# Arduino Nano not receiving MIDI messages

Tags: arduino-nano, midi

so I am currently creating a MIDI to CV module and am still having trouble with my MIDI input circuit. I am following [this circuit](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sQ8Uw7x-Vs0/VOatHJCRTGI/AAAAAAAAA9E/yD_TdRw_QKo/s1600/MIDI_Input_Schematic.png) as my guideline and am sending MIDI messages via MIDI interface with the use of this [cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BBMG43JZ). I am also using this software called [MIDIKeys](https://flit.github.io/projects/midikeys/) as a virtual keyboard for the MIDI notes. Unfortunately, every time I play a note on the keyboard the Arduino doesn't respond with the blink of the LED. I could really use some guidance on fixing this problem.

Below is also the code that I'm using:

```
#include <MIDI.h>  // Add Midi Library

#define LED 13    // Arduino Board LED is on Pin 13

//Create an instance of the library with default name, serial port and settings
//MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();
MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

void setup() {
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT); // Set Arduino board pin 13 to output
  MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI); // Initialize the Midi Library.
  MIDI.turnThruOff();
  MIDI.setHandleNoteOn(MyHandleNoteOn); 
  MIDI.setHandleNoteOff(MyHandleNoteOff); 
  Serial.begin(31250);
}

void loop() { // Main loop
  MIDI.read(); // Continuously check if Midi data has been received.
}

void MyHandleNoteOn(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) { 
  digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);  //Turn LED on
}

void MyHandleNoteOff(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) { 
  digitalWrite(LED,LOW);  //Turn LED off
}
```

Edit:
To verify that my laptop is sending a MIDI message I am using this [MIDI Monitor](https://www.snoize.com/midimonitor/)

Comment: how do you know that the PC is sending NoteOn events? ... please edit your question with a description of what you already tried

Comment: I doubt that the virtual keyboard sends serial messages to the com port